# How do I Create Custom ETCD Metrics for Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, etcd

I have set up a 3 node ETCD cluster and am using the default metrics via prometheus. I would like to create some more specific metrics for prometheus to scrape and report on.
I'm not sure if this is possible, the only answer I have seen is to use etcdctl to get info from ETCD and put it into a file that Prometheus scrapes.
Is there any way to add to or alter the existing metrics that ETCD exposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would try following (in this order):

1. Specify `--metrics extensive` flag to get additional metrics. Maybe what you need is already there! [code for this flag](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/691dcd51f6ef6a662d661e7b06bc216b43c9f0ca/server/etcdmain/help.go#L188)
2. Add your metric in etcd source code. If you know how to code, it should not be that hard. Example metric [registration](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/b571ec5e6781570f4b69620c6599944bc07752be/server/storage/backend/metrics.go#L87), and [usage](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/b571ec5e6781570f4b69620c6599944bc07752be/server/storage/backend/backend.go#L435). If you plan to go this way, it would be cool, to create Pull Request with your code later on!
3. If you can't code, then you may file feature request [on the github](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues) and hope for someone to implement it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm pretty sure it isn't in the extensive metrics (but I will double check). I Will have a look at the coding side of things and if all else fails add a feature request. I'll post an update when I have one.

Comment: Can confirm that the metrics I want to gather are not in the extensive metrics. Looks like I'll have to look at coding.